blade don't load my image in laravel
I want to set a image in my page but when I run my server don't load.

Same I tried to use <img src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/css/images/logo.png') }}">
or <img src="{{ asset('resources/css/images/logo.png') }}">
or <img src=" resources/css/images/logo.png  ">"


mi carpeta public la generó automaticamente laravel y tenia estas carpetas: 

Preguntas en inglés a [so].

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Para que la URL funcione, la imagen debería estar dentro del directorio public/. El navegador no tiene permisos para acceder directamente a los archivos en resources/.
La imagen debería estar en: public/css/images/logo.png

hola, intenté de la forma en que me dijiste, pero hace lo mismo, incluso uso el npm run build. Pero no sé por qué mi laravel cargo en la carpeta resources el css y js, porque el video del que me ando guiando de hace dos años muestra que esas carpetas deben ir dentro del public.  En la forma que me dijiste tuve que crear la carpeta css y dentro la carpeta images, pero aun así no funcionó.

si dejas la imagen en public/images/logo.png debería funcionar simplemente con <img src="/images/logo.png" >

cierto sin las llaves dobles funcionó. Gracias por la ayuda. :)
